# Eliminar espacio entre nav-pills vertical

Tags: bootstrap, nav, navbar

He creado un nav-pill vertical que incluye un numero en forma de aviso si se produce una condicion (extraída de una consulta SQL). El problema es que cuando tengo que mostrar el numero (como un badge) me crea un espacio entre los elementos del nav-pill.
Este es el codigo del nav-pill

```css
.badge-avisopedven{
   background:#cc6666;
   position:relative;
   top: -25px;
   right: -130px;
}

.nav-pills>li {
color: brown;
background-color: #E5F8FC;
}

.nav>li>a {
    padding-top: 3px;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class='container'>
  <ul class='nav nav-pills nav-stacked col-md-2'>
  <li class='active'><a data-toggle='pill' href='#UNO'><span>OPCION A</span></a></li><span class='badge badge-avisopedven'>7</span>
  <li><a data-toggle='pill' href='#DOS'><span>OPCION B</span></a></li>
  <li><a data-toggle='pill' href='#TRES'><span>OPCION D</span></a></li><span class='badge badge-avisopedven'>8</span>
  <li><a data-toggle='pill' href='#CUATRO'><span>OPCION E</span></a></li><span class='badge badge-avisopedven'>5</span>
  </ul>
  <div class='tab-content col-md-10'>
    <div id='UNO' class='tab-pane fade in active'>
      <h4 align='center'><span class='label label-primary'>UNO</span></h4>
    </div>
    <div id='DOS' class='tab-pane fade'>
      <h4 align='center'><span class='label label-primary'>DOS</span></h4>
    </div>
     <div id='TRES' class='tab-pane fade'>
      <h4 align='center'><span class='label label-primary'>TRES</span></h4>
    </div>
     <div id='CUATRO' class='tab-pane fade'>
      <h4 align='center'><span class='label label-primary'>CUATRO</span></h4>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

¿alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Da click derecho sobre los bordes y inspeccionar elemento, luego dime qué elemento está fallando para poder ayudarte mejor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.badge-avisopedven{
   background:#cc6666;
   position:absolute;
   top: 15px;
   left: 150px;
}

.nav-pills>li {
color: brown;
background-color: #E5F8FC;
}

.nav>li>a {
    padding-top: 3px;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
}

.nav > li {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class='container'>
  <ul class='nav nav-pills nav-stacked col-md-2'>
  <li class='active'><a data-toggle='pill' href='#UNO'>
    <span>OPCION A</span></a>
    <span class='badge badge-avisopedven'>7</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a data-toggle='pill' href='#DOS'><span>OPCION B</span></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a data-toggle='pill' href='#TRES'><span>OPCION D</span></a>
    <span class='badge badge-avisopedven'>8</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a data-toggle='pill' href='#CUATRO'><span>OPCION E</span></a>
    <span class='badge badge-avisopedven'>5</span>
  </li>
  </ul>
  <div class='tab-content col-md-10'>
    <div id='UNO' class='tab-pane fade in active'>
      <h4 align='center'><span class='label label-primary'>UNO</span></h4>
    </div>
    <div id='DOS' class='tab-pane fade'>
      <h4 align='center'><span class='label label-primary'>DOS</span></h4>
    </div>
     <div id='TRES' class='tab-pane fade'>
      <h4 align='center'><span class='label label-primary'>TRES</span></h4>
    </div>
     <div id='CUATRO' class='tab-pane fade'>
      <h4 align='center'><span class='label label-primary'>CUATRO</span></h4>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

El problema te lo estaban ocasionando los `<span>` con la clase `.badge-avisopedven`, que al estar posicionados relativamente ocupaban espacio debajo de cada uno de los `<li>`. Lo que hice fue meter esos `<span>` dentro de los `<li>` y cambiar el `position` de los `<li>` a `relative` y el de los `<span>` a `absolute` para poder posicionarlos cómodamente dentro del `<li>` padre.

Comment: Perfecto. Muchisimas gracias :-)

Answer (score 2):

Lo que te ocurre es que el numero no lo introduces en realidad dentro del nav-pill, si eliminas el css lo podrás observar.

Si introduces el `span` dentro del `li` obtendras el resultado deseado

```css
.badge-avisopedven{
   background:#cc6666;
   position:relative;
   top: -25px;
   right: -130px;
}

.nav-pills>li {
color: brown;
background-color: #E5F8FC;
}

.nav>li>a {
    padding-top: 3px;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class='container'>
  <ul class='nav nav-pills nav-stacked col-md-2'>
  <li class='active'><a data-toggle='pill' href='#UNO'><span>OPCION A</span>
</a><span class='badge badge-avisopedven'>7</span></li>
  <li><a data-toggle='pill' href='#DOS'><span>OPCION B</span></a></li>
  <li><a data-toggle='pill' href='#TRES'><span>OPCION D</span></a><span class='badge badge-avisopedven'>8</span></li>
  <li><a data-toggle='pill' href='#CUATRO'><span>OPCION E</span></a><span class='badge badge-avisopedven'>5</span></li>
  </ul>
  <div class='tab-content col-md-10'>
    <div id='UNO' class='tab-pane fade in active'>
      <h4 align='center'><span class='label label-primary'>UNO</span></h4>
    </div>
    <div id='DOS' class='tab-pane fade'>
      <h4 align='center'><span class='label label-primary'>DOS</span></h4>
    </div>
     <div id='TRES' class='tab-pane fade'>
      <h4 align='center'><span class='label label-primary'>TRES</span></h4>
    </div>
     <div id='CUATRO' class='tab-pane fade'>
      <h4 align='center'><span class='label label-primary'>CUATRO</span></h4>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```